# How to edit WordPress footer, do not know PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

This is the PHP code for the footer:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="site-info">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'flymag' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'flymag' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
            <span class="sep"> | </span>
            <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %2$s by %1$s.', 'flymag' ), 'FlyFreeMedia', '<a href="http://flyfreemedia.com/themes/flymag" rel="designer">FlyMag</a>' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </div>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

I'd like to remove the "Proudly powered by WordPress | Theme: FlyMag by FlyFreeMedia.
And replace it with Copyright 2015 | Company Name

Comment: Do you have permission to remove it? If not, removing it will most likely render the theme completely useless and would break the terms of use.

Comment: @APAD1 It's very unlikely that removing it would break the theme. None of the functions called in the snippet have side effects. Removing them should not cause any problems. The only exception I can think would be if the theme was monitoring it's own frontend for that link, which I seriously doubt.

Comment: @mtinsley how could you possibly know that without seeing the theme's functions file? I have seen many developers add that sort of protection to their themes. Regardless, if the developer wanted to give everyone the option to remove the copyright, they would have built that functionality into the theme's options.

Comment: @APAD1 I didn't claim to know one way or the other. I just said I doubt it will be an issue. I've seen a lot of developers waste time trying to protecting the links in themes and I've never encountered a theme that had the links in plaintext, but was monitoring the front-end code. By the way, that is not a "copyright". You can't add a theme to the WordPress repo and then restrict how it can be modified. Even if the developer is intentionally breaking the theme, you could disable that as well as remove the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove all of the code in the `site-info` element and replace it with your text:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="container">
    <div class="site-info">
        Copyright 2015 | Company Name
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
</div>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Regarding a concern raised in the comments, I don't think you will run into any issues with the theme breaking after removing this code, but it's always good to have a backup just in case. I *briefly* reviewed the [theme's functions file](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/flymag/1.03/functions.php) and I don't see anything that would cause such a problem.

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thanks for going the extra mile to check the functions file as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="site-info">
            <span class="sep"> Copyright 2015 | Company Name </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```